# Comodo Firewall HIPS (Paranoid Mode) Regedits

Tags: malware, firewalls, router

I've activated Comodo HIPS on "paranoid mode" to firstly see if I have an intrusion via my router but moreover to understand processes that occur.

As of recent, I have had a lot of requests to edit my 'root' registries and other files from my user application Firefox and even my general applications like Searchui.exe.

Is registry editing a normal part of application launch (i.e editing 'system preferences' reg key after launching searchui) or should I be suspicious?

From my understanding, automated registry edits without any form of installation, update or manual removal is an area of suspicion.